# Disable scrolling when hover a container

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to disable scrolling event when a user hovers on a container, there are some solutions on SO but they use jQuery and none of them seem to work or they are not the solution I'm looking for. I don't want to disable the scrollbar as that would cause bad user experience (scrollbar causing widths of the containers to increase/decrease). Is there any js way of achieving this?
For example,

```
<body>
<div onScroll={()=> }>Container</div>
Content here
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

that ?

```js
const scroll_stopper = document.querySelector('#StopSrollonHover')

scroll_stopper.onmouseover = () =>
  {
  document.body.classList.add('noScroll')
  }
scroll_stopper.onmouseout = () =>
  {
  document.body.classList.remove('noScroll')
  }
```

```css
.noScroll {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
#StopSrollonHover {
  display    : block;
  margin-top : 25vh;
  height     : 100px;
  background :  yellow;
}
```

```html
  <div id="StopSrollonHover">  </div>
```

Comment: I'm really looking for a way of achieving this with JS, I don't really like the solution with CSS

Comment: @User123123 Why ? each part has a role that complements the other. HTML body is made to present useful content, javascript is made to add interaction, and css is made to handle presentation. This represents a form of maturity in the design of systems. Would you like us to go back to the days when everything was mixed up?