# Maintaining scroll position when navigating back from dynamically loaded AJAX content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, scroll

I am working on a web application where I dynamically load content into a div through multiple AJAX API calls. Each item in the list is a hyperlink that leads to another page. I want to implement a functionality that allows users to navigate back to the list page and maintain their scroll position.

I have tried using window.scrollTo while storing scroll position in my localstorage to achieve this, but it's not working as expected. The issue arises when the user navigates to another page after items are loaded in subsequent API calls. Upon returning back, the API calls cannot be repeated, leading to incorrect scroll positions.

I am seeking guidance on how to maintain the scroll position effectively when users navigate back from dynamically loaded content. Any help or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried this code by storing the scroll position and go to that position on page load:

```
// Code used to store scroll position before navigating
localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', window.scrollY);

// Code used to restore scroll position on returning to the list page
const storedScrollPosition = localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition');
if (storedScrollPosition !== null) {
    window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(storedScrollPosition));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382962/disable-scrolling-when-hover-a-container/68383229#68383229

Comment: Sir, if you can find even one similarity between those two questions, I will remove mine right now.

Comment: the questions are different but the method could be the same. don't you see it? (and I am not your "Sir", I find this offensive)

Comment: If my comment offends you, I sincerely apologize. But that question is about how to disable scrolling on hover element, On the other hand, i need to maintain scrolling position when the user goes back into that list page (for example, a product list page, when the user clicks the name of the product, it redirects him to details page, but when the user get back to this page, they should land on the product which can be appened by nth number of API call)

Comment: try to remove scrolling (CSS -> `overflow: hidden !important;`) until your ajax append data is over, then remove this css to get scroll bar back with the same offset position as before

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could send me some sample code or something because i believe there is a miscommunication regarding my issue when using window.scrollTo, it is only scrolling to the first set of items (the page load did not occur for the nth number of the API call).
However, I truly appreciate your assistance!

Comment: What did you call `page` element ? If you use ajax call that  should be `<section>` elements

Comment: It is your question,  you have to present a [minimal and representative part of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *You also must read SO guideslines and folow the links in [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)